# Why does nextjs return an error after exiting the MSAL oauth process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, msal.js

I'm getting an error building a website with next.js.  I've build the site for production running, and after authenticating I get this error below. I have integrated MSAL for authentication which lets me control access through Azure AD.  After the Oauth loop I get the following error. I have no idea what's causing it as I'm new to next.js and have previously used Express.  After some research I found that someone had solved it with <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> but I can't seem to fix it with that either.

[image]

**Code**

index.js (Main Page)

```
import {
    AuthenticatedTemplate,
    UnauthenticatedTemplate,
    useMsal,
} from '@azure/msal-react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import { Logo } from '../services/components'
import * as React from 'react';

function SignInButton() {
    // useMsal hook will return the PublicClientApplication instance you provided to MsalProvider
    const { instance } = useMsal();

    return (<button onClick={() => instance.loginRedirect()} className={styles.auth }><h2>Sign In</h2></button>);
}

function SignOut() {
    const { instance } = useMsal();

    return (
        <div className={styles.grid}>
            <button onClick={ () => instance.logoutRedirect() } className={styles.auth}>
                <h2>Sign Out</h2>
            </button>
        </div>
        )
}

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
            </Head>
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                <title>SD Menu</title>
                <main className={styles.main }>
                    <div className={styles.container}>
                        <div className={styles.grid}>
                            <Logo />
                        </div>
                            <p className={styles.description}>
                            Choose a service from below.
                        </p>
                <div className={styles.grid}>

                    <Link href="/pcdecomservice" className={styles.card}>
                        <h2>Decomission a Computer</h2>
                        <p>Decomission a computer automatically in line with the SOP.</p>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href="/" className={styles.card}>
                        <h2>Create a New User</h2>
                        <p>Create a new user with predefined groups and settings.</p>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href="/" className={styles.card}>
                        <h2>Enable a mailbox</h2>
                        <p>Enable a mailbox for use.</p>
                    </Link>
                            </div>
                        <SignOut/>

                    </div>

                </main>
                </AuthenticatedTemplate>

            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <title>SD Login</title>
                <div className={styles.container}>
                    <div className={styles.main}>
                        <div className={styles.grid}>
                            <Logo />
                        </div>
                        <p className={styles.description}>
                            Please sign in to access this service
                        </p>
                        <div className={styles.grid}>
                            <SignInButton />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Components.js

```
import Image from 'next/image';


export function Logo() {

    return (
        <Image
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/bb/Kingspan_Group_%28building_materials_company%29_logo_with_lion.svg/220px-Kingspan_Group_%28building_materials_company%29_logo_with_lion.svg.png"
            alt="Kingspan Logo"
            width="220"
            height="108"
        />
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more minutes I decided to re-run the code in Next Dev.

The error was much better and pointed out that the  tags had more than one child element.  I resolved it by changing it to the below:

**Before**

```
   <Link className={styles.card}>
      <h2>Create a New User</h2>
      <p>Create a new user with predefined groups and settings.</p>
   </Link>
```

**After**

```
<Link href="/" >
   <a className={styles.card}>
      <h2>Create a New User</h2>
      <p>Create a new user with predefined groups and settings.</p>
   </a>
</Link>
```

Turns out I was just being stupid and took an article to remove the hrefs from the  tag and change them to a  tag too literally.